# Delete from a table matching one criteria where there are rows in same table matching different criteria?

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the mega title... I was trying to be descriptive enough. I've got a table that contains event attendance data that has some erroneous data in it. The table definition is kind of like this:

```
id (row id)
date
company_name
attendees
```

It ended up with some cases where for a given date, there are two entries matching a company_name and date but one has attendees=0 and the other has attendees>0. In those cases, I want to discard the ones where attendees=0.

I know you can't join on the same table while deleting, so please consider this query to be pseudocode that shows what I want to accomplish.

```
DELETE FROM attendance a WHERE a.attendees=0 AND a.date IN (SELECT b.date FROM attendance b WHERE b.attendees > 0 AND b.company_name = a.company_name);
```

I also tried to populate a temporary table with the ids of the rows I want to delete, but that query hangs because of the IN (SELECT ...) clause. My table has thousands of rows so that just maxes out the CPU and then times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ugly thing should work (using alias permit to avoid the `You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause` error)

```
DELETE FROM attendance
WHERE (attendees, date, company_name)
IN (SELECT c.a, c.d, c.c 
    FROM
     (SELECT MIN(attendees) a, date d, company_name c
      FROM attendance
      GROUP BY date, company_name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as c);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c591/1)

Comment: Hmm... If there was only one row for a company on a given date, wouldn't this delete that one regardless of the attendees value?

Comment: I tried it in sqlfiddle (I didn't know about that site. very cool!) and it left me with only one row in the table. Using your table as an example, I only want to delete the first row. The rest are correct. I only want to delete when there are duplicate rows for a company on a date, and I only want to delete ones with 0 attendees.

Comment: @wtbgtr ok, didn't understand that. See edited answer (and sqlFiddle)

Comment: Down the road, in other code, I need to count absences for companies and attendances (not necessarily attendees, although that info is relevant elsewhere). And there can be more than one attendance by a company if multiple representatives are there. I want to select count of absences or attendances (in separate queries) grouped by company and date. I believe it would work except I have erroneous these erroneous records of absences (attendees = 0)

Comment: @wtbgtr You're welcome. For your `Down the road`, I must admit I didn't understand if it's another question or not, and if it's a question, I didn't understand the problem...

Comment: No, I was just trying to explain why the table was set up the way it is. It's kind of mimicking a bureaucracy :)